# Remove "X" button in Swing JDialog

Tags: java, swing

Is there a way to remove the close button ("X") from the `JDialog` title bar?

Comment: I have seen some applications that show another dialog if you press the close button telling you to press one of the other buttons instead. Genius!

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Well, the only thing you'd need to do that would be to add an event listener to the `JDialog` when it's being closed, and then show a new `JDialog` (either by extending the `JDialog` class or by using `JOptionPane`) to tell the user which buttons they should press. This dialog would also have to have only an `OK` button.

Answer (score 60):

You can remove the whole dialog title by calling `dialog.setUndecorated(true)` but this means that the dialog can't be moved anymore.

You can also execute `dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE)` to prevent that the button does anything.

Besides that, I don't think that there's a way to remove the `X` completely.

Answer (score 13):

I believe that you can call `dialog.setUndecorated(true)` to remove the title bar. Not sure about just the 'X' though.

Removing the 'X' may not be a great idea, though, as you want your users to be able to close the dialog easily.

Best bet is to control what happens when the users clicks the 'X' by using `dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation` or a `WindowListener`.

Comment: Thanks for talking about `WindowListener`; it's going to be good for people who want the warning sound when the user attempts to close the dialog.

Answer (score 12):

As of Java 1.7 (AKA Dolphin or Java 7), you can not disable or remove the close button on a Window. You can remove/disable the maximize button with `frame.setResizable(false)` and you can remove the minimize and maximize buttons by using a `java.awt.Dialog` or a class that extends it, such as `javax.swing.JDialog`. You can remove the title bar, borders, and buttons with `frame.setUndecorated(true)`, and you can have full control over the visibility of all buttons in the title bar (while losing some cross-platform compatibility and OS integration) with `frame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true)` (assuming it's a JFrame or JDialog). This is all the control I see possible with the current JDK.

Comment: This is "will not fix" on [bug parade](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5085932).

Comment: This isn't entirely correct. Subclassing / instantiating a JDialog on OS X (tested on El Capitan) does not remove any buttons from the title bar, nor does any combination of settings (and yes, I tried every combination). Only `setUndecorated(true)` removes them all, but along with it goes the title bar.  You can certainly modify the behavior of the title bar buttons, but as for appearance...it's a very tricky situation that I've spent too much time on w/unsatisfactory solutions and non-portable code.

Comment: @EntangledLoops Thanks for contributing your comment! Although it's true that JDialog does not _remove_ the minimize/"maximize" buttons on OS X dialogs, it does disable the minimize one. I don't have a Mac on-hand to test this on but I am willing to bet the maximize button just resizes it, and if you set `dialog.setResizable(false)`, the green button will become disabled, as well! Anyway, as I said in my answer, it's upsetting that we don't have full control over this, but I can imagine how nightmarish that might be for JSE creators to program in for all platforms. ;3

Comment: The best I could do was rendering a png of the title bar as I want it on a size-padded undecorated frame, and then implementing drag-and-drop code that detects if the user clicked w/in the title region. A hack....but it works.

Comment: @EntangledLoops Best of luck finding a solution that works for you! Perhaps also look into some 3rd-party Look-And-Feel libraries; they're very powerful and could provide the answer you need :D

Answer (score 6):

Here is my experience:

- Tried using `setUndecorated(true)`: Made the whole `Dialog` invisible.
- Tried `setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE)`: This didn't change the behavior at all. My dialog box still closed. Setting the default close operation to `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE` delegates the close operation to the `windowClosing()` method of a registered `WindowListener`.

What worked for me was:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
//Remove any existing WindowListeners
for (WindowListener wl : this.getWindowListeners()) {
    this.removeWindowListener(wl);
}
this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        if ("Optional condition") {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You cannot close this window");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, set it to be PL&F decorated and remove the component by name.

Comment: What is PL&F? Thanks.

Comment: PL&F is Pluggable Look & Feel. The ugly way Swing can take on an arbitrary Look & Feel.

Answer (score -3):

```
static public void removeButtons(Component c){
    if (c instanceof AbstractButton){
        String accn = c.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleName();
        Container p=c.getParent();
        //log.debug("remove button %s from %s",accn,p.getClass().getName());
        c.getParent().remove(c);
    }
    else if (c instanceof Container){
        //log.debug("processing components of %s",c.getClass().getName());
        Component[] comps = ((Container)c).getComponents();
        for(int i = 0; i<comps.length; ++i)
            removeButtons(comps[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: this will remove any buttons added to the dialog, not dialog closing buttons.

Comment: This has no effect on title bar buttons (OS X).

Comment: This is actually rather funny and leaves your app in a hilariously unusable state if you _ever_ use buttons x3

Comment: @Supuhstar Yes, if you take a close look at the code, you will see that the code removes buttons that the programmer adds (these buttons are instances of subclasses of `AbstractButton`), but the close button of the `JDialog` is native; it isn't an instance of a subclass of `AbstractButton`.

Comment: Often the close button on a dialog is indeed an AbstractButton, particularly if a non-native look and feel is used