# JDialog Close Icon Query?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I would like remove the close icon present in the `JDialog` Option. How can I Achieve this?

Requirement: Trying to re-design the default Dialog Structure by removing the 'x' or close icon

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Please clarify your question and provide sample code.

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942056/remove-x-button-in-swing-jdialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't remove it (and keep the title bar) but you can disable its functionality by using:

```
dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

`dialog.setUndecorated(true);` should do it for you (a method inherited from the [java.awt.Dialog](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setUndecorated%28boolean%29) class), but there are some catches, most notably that this method will also remove the title bar, making it impossible to move the dialog around the screen.

This [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942056/remove-x-button-in-swing-jdialog) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

IT is always beeter to override the setDefaultCloseOperation method if you want to perform some extra operations. How ever you can not stop the dialog from getting closed. I tried but was not able to stop it from closing. But yes by overiding the setDefaultcloseoperation method i was able to perform some list cleanup and file closing operations.
Try to override the function as follows.

```
public class LaunchGenerator extends JDialog 
{
public LaunchGenerator()
{
this.setSize(1200, 900);
        contentPanel =new JPanel();
        contentPanel.setLayout(null);
        this.setContentPane(contentPanel);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(2); // you can write anything inside the function.
}

public void setDefaultCloseOperation(int i)
{
    if(i==2)
    {
        dispose();
                     //and all other things that you want to do. such as file      closing     and list cleanups.etc ,etc.
    }

}
```

Comment: a) don't override setDefaultCloseOperation b) don't use magic numbers c) don't do any manual sizing/locating (aka: null layoutManager)

Comment: Iam very Sorry for the giving improper solution. Can anyone please explain? why we should not override the setDefaultCloseOperation method.It will be helpfull for me to improve my answer. Thanks in advance.