# Way to force KDE to not allow minimization of Java JDialog elements?

Tags: java, linux, awt, kde-plasma

I have a Java application that uses JDialog boxes for displaying certain information.  The JDialog boxes are not minimizable (and shouldn't be), but we've run into a problem specific to Linux KDE desktop (4.3.5, but I believe it probably applies to 4.x).  KDE window decorators appear to be overriding Java's and are allowing minimization of JDialog boxes.  Windows/Solaris/Linux (GNOME desktops) do not allow minimization of JDialog boxes, it appears to only be KDE.  Is there an attribute that I am missing or other way to explicitly say this JDialog box should never be minimized?

Other potentially useful info:
Java: JRE 1.6.0_17
Linux: openSUSE and SUSE Enterprise Server (both running KDE 4.3.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I cannot find a way to navigate around the JDialog minimization, I found a work around.  Setting the visibility of the display to false, then toggling back to true causes the minimized window to become visible and available again:

```
myDialog.setVisible(false);
myDialog.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try removing the whole dialog title by calling `dialog.setUndecorated(true)` but this means that the dialog can't be moved anymore.

This related question also has some pointers: [Remove "X" button in Swing JDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942056/remove-x-button-in-swing-jdialog)

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  Making the dialog box immovable is not an option though. :(

Comment: It's a big trade off for sure. Other than searching around here for alternate solutions (Java doesn't give you the kind of platform-specific control you always want, especially when it comes to UI, unfortunately), I think you might be up the creek on this one.

Comment: Agreed :( Thought I'd post this question in case someone had managed to conquer it though.

Comment: Hmm, this is one of those cases where searching on Yahoo/Bing provides way more useful results (though I dont know if they're going to help... yet)