# JDialog decorated true but without close button

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, jprogressbar

Okay, researching I saw a lot of posts regarding to the topic "hide close button from dialogs" but none of them solved my problem.The thing is I have this Dialog:

[image]

which I would like to keep the decoration (borders, transparency and etc) but I would like to hide or remove the close button component cos I will handle this with the cancel button.

If I use

```
setUndecorated(true);
getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.NONE);
```

the result I will get is

[image]

which for me its completely terrible(not at all here since nothings on background)...so I ask: is there another way to handle this problem with dialog or setUndecorated and getRootPane are absolute? Futher suggestions are very welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to the answers in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942056/remove-x-button-in-swing-jdialog, it doesn't seem possible without creating your own `JDialog`

Comment: I think I will deal with another JDialog pumping up alerting that this will call the search. That might be easier instead of handle with one native API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot remove the "X" button without messing with UI code (low level LAF or even native api), I dont know is it worth of the effort.
However, if you REALLY REAAAALLLLLY need such functionality (and you will get lots of money for that;P) you can always write native code that would hide the X button (yes that is totally possible), but again, that is not worth of your time :)